# How to properly use new operator (C++)

Tags: c++, class, allocation

I have class Stack :

```
class Stack {
private:
      int top;
      int capacity;
      int *storage;
public:
      Stack(int capacity) {
        if (capacity <= 0)
              throw string("Stack's capacity must be positive");
        storage = new int[capacity];
        this->capacity = capacity;
        top = -1;
      }

      void push(int value) {
            if (top == capacity)
                  throw string("Stack's underlying storage is overflow");
            top++;
            storage[top] = value;
      }

...
```

and I try to allocate it with

```
Stack* s = new Stack (100);
```

When I try to execute any of Stack's functions (push for example), I get an error C2228: left of '.push' must have class/struct/union. Can someone explain how to do it correct way?

Comment: Do you have a particular reason for `s` to be a pointer?

Comment: If I don't make it a pointer, than I get an error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'Stack *' to 'Stack'

Comment: That's because you're using `new` to construct the `Stack`. Unless you need pointer semantics, you can just do `Stack stack = Stack(100);`

Comment: @HuuNguyen Or `Stack s(100);`

Comment: Something tells me this class doesn't have a destructor (or other necessary components a la the rule of three).

Comment: @NathanOliver, brevity may be less important than clarity for this particular learning moment :P.

Comment: You show some code, but *not* the code which generates the error. Why?

Comment: If you want to keep the pointer, i.e., `Stack *s`, then you can call `push()` like this, `s->push()`, using pointer dereference notation.

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

s is the pointer to the stack. Access the class methods(functions) using `->` operator.

In your case it would be
`s->push(10);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling the push as `obj.push(value)`. This is wrong, when using pointer to objects then you will access members using ->. So try `obj->push(value)`

Answer (score 0):

`s` is a pointer to the stack in your code. To access the methods of an object, the `.` operator is used. So, you should first dereference the pointer, and then use the `.` operator. This is equivalent to using the `->` operator.

`s->push()` is equivalent to `(*s).push()`.

Or you need not declare a pointer to the stack, and instead just declare the object. The code would read `stack s(100);`

Answer (score 0):

The correct way use methods that are dynamically allocated is to call the methods with ->. So you should call the push method like this: s->push(int x).

```
int main()
{
  Stack * s = new Stack(5);
  s->push(60);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Others already gave good answers. I just wanted to add a minor comment. Unless you have a specific reason to create a pointer and if you insist on using dot(.) instead of -> you may change your code to:

```
Stack s(100);
```

Then you will able to call:

```
s.push(value);
```